# What gives lenses a cinematic feel?

Tags: lens, equipment-recommendation, cinema, mood

Maybe this is far to broad a question, but I'm not sure I can do better:

I'm interested in using a cheap DSLR for movies (hacked Panasonic GH1).  I am a good artist, but I don't know anything about lenses other than: more expensive gets you more light and less edge distortion.  My only experience with a DSLR is 2 years with a K-x and the cheap 18-55 kit lens.

**Do you have any general advice on which attributes of a lens are most important in getting a cinematic feel?**

Let's assume for the sake of answering the question that otherwise I'm a cinematography pro.

Comment: Cinematic stills are on topic — cinematic digital video goes to http://avp.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: That said, what you want is nice rendering of out-of-focus areas (good bokeh) and the potential for a nice wide aperture. I think the Panasonic Leica 25mm f/1.4 is almost a no-brainer.

Comment: And, if you're willing to entertain answers focused on stills rather than video, I'd love to see this question stay here rather than get migrated.

Answer (score 9):

The comments about throwing the background out of focus are definitely on-the-money.  I would also suggest that longer lenses tend to yield more "cinematic" results.  (Which is not to say that wide / slightly-wide perspectives can't also be dramatic. But when shooting video with a wide lens, perspective distortion starts to get quite noticeable as you pan around.)

However, the lens is just part of getting a cinematic feel.

Just as important are using composition, lighting, and post-processing to heighten the dramatic feel.  I'm going to do a Flickr search for "cinematic" and choose a few examples:

http://www.flickr.com/photos/garytube/6637602571/lightbox/ - 
Features of note:

- Framing/composition within a "letterbox" aspect ratio.
- Tight control of the color pallete
- The scene is slightly flattened, which suggests that a long lens was used
- Heavy vignetting

http://www.flickr.com/photos/autoidiodyssey/6177520729/

- Letterboxed
- Muted palette
- Long lens

http://www.flickr.com/photos/serni/6098984689/lightbox/

- Letterboxed
- Dramatic lighting
- Slightly-wide lens

http://www.flickr.com/photos/paradeinthesky/2091008517/

- Look at that high-contrast lighting!
- Muted color palette
- Long lens (probably)

Also check out the Cinematic pool for more:  http://www.flickr.com/groups/cinematicinfluences/pool/with/4112078800/

Comment: I've undeleted this as it seemed to be a fine answer regarding getting that "cinematic" look and feel with a digital camera. I think the examples linked are good, although there might be some even better ones from that pool.

Comment: Oh!  I've gotta say that I was a little surprised to find that my answer was still here =)  For what it's worth, the reason that I deleted it in the first place was that marienbad specifically was asking about lenses and I was worried that I side-stepped the question too much.

Comment: Don't worry too much if your answer doesn't specifically answer 100% exactly what someone may ask. It is often the case that people do not know what to ask, and use the terms they are familiar with. Additionally, this is a community site, and answers usually have value beyond simply answering the original question. We are a prime target for internet searches, and many people might read the answers to a question...if the answer is somewhat broad relative to what was asked, that is ok, so long as it *is* a valid answer overall.

Answer (score 1):

A lens for cinematic effect can have two characteristics:

1. A wide angle(for letterbox aspect ratio)
2. With very high aperture(for getting bokeh effect ie. the out of focus effect)

A suitable lens can be as mentioned in the comment a Panasonic Leica 25mm f/1.4

Apart from this the most cinematic effect is achieved in post-processing of the image like letterboxing, reducing the saturation, adding viginity, etc.

Comment: The resulting aspect ratio has very little to do with the angle of view of your lens.